# VBA copying data from one workbook to specific cells in another, based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks and need to copy over data from rows that have a "yes" in the 26th column to specific cells in the destination workbook.
I currently have the following code attached to a button on the source sheet:

```
Sub exportData()

Dim LastRow As Integer 
Dim i As Integer
Dim erow As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 26).Value = "Yes" Then


    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Select
     Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\GI New Starter Tracker 2017edit.xlsx"
    Worksheets("Main").Select
    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    'ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$3000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The code works fine, however it copies over the entire row, but I only need to copy over certain information like "firstname", "Surname" "Date of birth". The target workbook doesnt have exactly the same headings so I need to be able to specify which column.

Ive been pulling my hair out and would really appreciate any help.

Thanks :)

Comment: This can be easily done with excel formula, but only if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You'll need to change the column number to the corresponding columns in your workbooks....

```
Sub exportData()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim erow As Integer
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim firstName, surName, DoB

    Set SourceSheet = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = SourceSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\GI New Starter Tracker 2017edit.xlsx")
    Set DestSheet = wbk.Sheets("Main")

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If SourceSheet.Cells(i, 26).Value = "Yes" Then
            'change the column numbers to the relevant number
            firstName = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 23).Value
            surName = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 24).Value
            DoB = SourceSheet.Cells(i, 25).Value

            erow = DestSheet.Cells(DestSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            'change the column numbers to the relevant number
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 10).Value = firstName
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 11).Value = surName
            DestSheet.Cells(erow, 12).Value = DoB
        End If
    Next i

    wbk.Save
    wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You sir are a LEGEND! Much appreciated. I had to make sure some sort of data was written in column A of the destination sheet to get it working but it works like a dream.